# How do these two OR logical statements work?

Tags: python, logic

As the title says. These two statements are different and yeld different results for a = 1 and a = 2.

```py
a == (1 or 2)

a == 1 or 2
```

All I wanted to do is to easier type in many comparison OR statements.

Comment: I'm hesitant to close it because this is two questions, but this is basically a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value). The difference between the two though is `a == (1 or 2)` vs `(a == 1) or 2`. If you want to compare against multiple values, see the link.

Comment: `(1 or 2)` limits it to mean "is a 1 or 2?". `a == 1 or 2` will return 2 if `a != 1`.

Comment: Thanks. You can close it.

Comment: Should I add it as an answer?

Comment: Nah, you don't have to.